# How do I build a HMAC code in Elm?

Tags: cryptography, elm, hmac

I'm trying to implement HMAC in Elm,
but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.
Some help would be greatly appreciated

```
type alias HashFunction =
    String -> String


encrypt64 : HashFunction -> String -> String -> String
encrypt64 =
    encrypt 64


encrypt : Int -> HashFunction -> String -> String -> String
encrypt blockSize hasher message key =
    let
        keySize =
            String.length key

        keyWithCorrectSize =
            if keySize > blockSize then
                hexStringToUtf8String (hasher key)
            else if keySize < blockSize then
                String.padRight blockSize (Char.fromCode 0) key
            else
                key

        keyCodePoints =
            keyWithCorrectSize
                |> String.toList
                |> List.map Char.toCode

        partA =
            keyCodePoints
                |> List.map (Bitwise.xor 54 >> Char.fromCode)
                |> String.fromList

        partB =
            keyCodePoints
                |> List.map (Bitwise.xor 92 >> Char.fromCode)
                |> String.fromList
    in
        message
            |> String.append partA
            |> hasher
            |> hexStringToUtf8String
            |> String.append partB
            |> hasher



-- Utils


hexStringToUtf8String : String -> String
hexStringToUtf8String input =
    input
        |> String.toList
        |> List.Extra.greedyGroupsOf 2
        |> List.map (String.fromList >> hexStringToUtf8Char)
        |> String.fromList


hexStringToUtf8Char : String -> Char
hexStringToUtf8Char input =
    case Hex.fromString input of
        Ok v ->
            Char.fromCode v

        Err err ->
            Debug.crash err
```

You can find the related code here: https://github.com/icidasset/ongaku-ryoho/blob/master/src/App/Sources/Crypto/Hmac.elm (which includes doc tests)

**edit:** To be more clear... my current code here doesn't output a valid HMAC,
and I would like to know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Elm SHA library, I think the problem (or at least a problem) is that the output from the hash is hex encoded. HMAC calls the hash function twice, feeding the first output back into the second call, and this needs to be the raw SHA bytes, rather than a hex string.

So you need to decode the hex output from the first call to `hasher`, after it is applied to `partA`.

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely one of the problems. Not quite there yet unfortunately... I've updated my code above. Does that look ok to you?

Comment: Ok, so a buddy of mine took the other way around and made `partB` a hex-encoded string and that seems to work. It's weird that my wannabe solution doesn't work though... Anyhow, this was definitely the one and only problem. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you got it working at last. I see the SHA library accepts Hex input if you use a "0x" prefix, so I guess that's what you mean here.